# ¿Utilizar Activity.runOnUiThread() o Handler.post(Runnable) para actualizar el Thread principal?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, hilos

Muy buenas, tengo una duda relacionada en cuándo tengo que utilizar (o porqué) **Activity.runOnUiThread()** en vez de, o al revés de **Handler.post(Runnable)** para actualizar por ejemplo un *TextView* o *ProgressBar*, o en su defecto, debo de utilizar **Asyntask**.

He estado buscando información en los siguientes enlaces, pero aún no tengo una respuesta clara. ¿Cuál es la mejor opción dependiendo de cada caso?

[Android: What's the difference between Activity.runOnUiThread and View.post?](http://Android:%20What's%20the%20difference%20between%20Activity.runOnUiThread%20and%20View.post?)

[runOnUiThread vs Handler.post(runnable action) ?](http://www.anddev.org/runonuithread_vs_handlerpostrunnable_action_-t9375.html)

[Difference between Handler.post(Runnable r) and Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable r)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452884/difference-between-handler-postrunnable-r-and-activity-runonuithreadrunnable)

Comment: Ninguna si son en el mismo hilo, el handler para comunicacion de hilos puedes. donde lo crees en ese hilo se ejecutara. El handler permite enviar mensajes para hacer un mejor filtrado de peticiones a otro hilo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La diferencia entre `Activity.runOnUiThread()` y `Handler.post(Runnable r)` es que el `runOnUiThread` **solo ejecuta una acción específica desde un thread** que estés ejecutando **sobre una view** (un componente, ya sea TextView u otro) **del hilo principal**, es decir, un componente de tu app.

El Handler.post(Runnable r), sirve básicamente para lo mismo, pero existe una pequeña diferencia y es que con Handler.post() **puedes acceder a los componentes o variables de otros thread y no solo al hilo principal** como con `runOnUiThread`.

Si solo quieres modificar un componente del hilo principal, te recomiendo que uses `runOnUiThread()` ya que así no tendrás problemas.

Un ejemplo de uso de `runOnUiThread()` es:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       // Código a ejecutar
   }
}
```

Un ejemplo de uso de `Handler.post(Runnable r)` es:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Código a ejecutar
    }
 });
```

Otra cosa es utilizar `AsyncTask`, que tiene métodos específicos para poder crear acciones en el hilo principal, pero no poder acceder a sus componentes, por ejemplo, un `AsycnTask` puede utilizar sus métodos para crear un dialogo con una barra de proceso y actuar sobre el, pero no podrá acceder a un `TextView` el hilo principal.

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
private class HiloEnSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask <(los parametros que recibe o que le envias), (el tipo de datos que maneja durante la ejecución), (el tipo de datos en devuelve)> {

        public HiloEnSegundoPlano(){
            // Es el constructor
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Este método puede actuar sobre el hilo principal y por ejmplo,
            // aquí es donde abririas un dialogo con una barra de proceso.
        }

        @Override
        protected (el tipo de datos en devuelve) doInBackground((los parametros que recibe o que le envias)... variable (ejemplo: "args")) {
            // Aquí iria el código que quieres ejecutar en segundo plano.

            publishProgress(el tipo de datos que maneja durante la ejecución); 
            // Es opcional y con el puedes pasar un valor y llamar a onProgressUpdate()

            cancel(true); 
            //Es opcional y con el puedes cancelar la tarea y llamará al método onCancelled() en vez de pasar onPostExecute(). Puedes comprobar si se ha cancelado con isCancelled().

            return (el valor del tipo de datos en devuelve);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate((tipo de dato)... variable (ejemplo: "args")) {
            // Aquí podrias tener alguna acción en el cuadro de dialogo abierto, por ejmplo,
            // repetir un codigo 50 veces para dibujar un proceso de carga.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute((tipo de datos en devuelve) variable) {
            // Aqui cerrarias el cuadro de dialogo, en caso, de que todo se haya ejecutado 
            // correctamente.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled ((tipo de datos en devuelve) variable) {
            // Aqui cerrarias el cuadro de dialogo, en caso, de que se haya producido algun
            // error en la carga y desde el método "doInBackground" hayas ejecutado "cancel(true);"
            // Podrías mostrar también un mensaje de error.
        }
```

Espero haberte ayudado con tu duda. Si tienes alguna otra duda o no entiendes algo de lo que te explico, por favor déjame un comentario y te lo aclarare.

¡¡Mucha suerte!!

Comment: Una aclaración sumando a la respuesta, es que el Handler tiene que ser inicializado en el main thread caso contrario vas a tener un error.

Comment: Con un asyntask, dentro de el puedes obtener un elemento del layout? es decir un TextView para así si tienes que mostrar diferentes datos del proceso como un log?

Comment: Lamentablemente AsyncTask ha sido etiquetada como obsoleta a partir del API Nivel 30: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask