# Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android

Tags: java, android, json

Intento realizar una petición de un recurso `json` usando `HttpURLConnection`

Testeo el siguiente código en **onCreate()**

```
   try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/testrealm/api/v1/status");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        Log.d(TAG, "get json: " + in.toString());
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Error** en la petición

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo ...
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

**Log Error** entero

```
06-10 14:32:21.113 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: realm.test.app.testrealm, PID: 11702
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{realm.test.app.testrealm/realm.test.app.testrealm.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1161)
      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
      at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
      at realm.test.app.testrealm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Documentación de [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html?hl=es)

Comment: El error de te dice que no puedes hacer operaciones de red en el hilo principal debes introducir ese código en un hilo aparte como por ejemplo en un AsyncTask. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **NetworkOnMainThreadException**: se provoca cuando tratas de realizar
> operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.

Si usas **[StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html)** para permitir cualquier operación, funciona pero estas desactivando una política que se supone no debe permitir cierto comportamiento en la aplicación, en este caso operaciones en el Hilo principal, esto se usa principalmente para desarrollo, para producción **no deberías usarlo**.

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Usa [**runOnUiThread()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

**KOTLIN**:

```
runOnUiThread {
    try {
        proceso() //Realizar aquí tu proceso!                    
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.message)
    }
}
```

**JAVA:**

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {  
               proceso(); //Realizar aquí tu proceso!                    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Otras opciones son [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) y también [**Handler.post()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).

Encontré este articulo excelente para más información: **["Tareas en segundo plano en Android (I): Thread y AsyncTask"](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/tareas-en-segundo-plano-en-android-i-thread-y-asynctask/)** (blog de Salvador Gómez).

Answer (score 4):

**Deberías usar AsynkTask:**

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/testrealm/api/v1/status");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            Log.d(TAG, "get json: " + in.toString());
            urlConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
});
```

Si necesitas saber cuando recibes respuesta y/o modificar vistas después de la llamada usa AsynkTask de esta manera:

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
           URL url = new URL("http://localhost/testrealm/api/v1/status");
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            Log.d(TAG, "get json: " + in.toString());
            urlConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
          // your code here
          super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
     }
};
```

Comment: esto debería de ponerse dentro del onCreate o cómo? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Agregar el siguiente código antes de realizar la petición web con `HttpURLConnection`

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: amigo esto "resuelve" pero no es correcto, una analogía es que exista un policía en la entrada de un banco, pero tengas una "política" la cual impide al policía detener al ladrón si usa un arma de juguete.

Answer (score 1):

Como otra opción a este problema, que también me lo pase por las manos, es implementar tu código dentro de un `runOnUiThread()` que permitirá acceder a las variables del hilo principal, ya que ese es justo el problema.

En esta pregunta, explico este método:

[¿Utilizar Activity.runOnUiThread() o Handler.post(Runnable) para actualizar el Thread principal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13206/4684)

En cuanto vuelva a tener ocasión probare tu solución y así conocer bien otras posibles soluciones.

Comment: Esta no es otra opción, es una opción valida y correcta,  desactivar "StrictMode" no es correcto.

Comment: Lo de `StrictMode` no lo sabia, pero es bueno aprender estas cosas. Lo que puedes o no hacer. Gracias. :)

Answer (score 1):

Este tema siempre da de que hablar. Definitivamente desactivar políticas no es la opción.

Pero ojo que esto tiene mucho que ver con cómo quieres hacer las cosas, en mi experiencia he visto los siguientes escenarios:

1. Ejecutar un proceso largo en segundo plano informando al usuario de su progreso
2. Ejecutar un proceso largo en segundo plano sin que el usuario sepa de ello
3. Ejecutar un proceso en segundo plano y realizar otro proceso de acuerdo a su resultado.

Por tanto, no sé cual sea tu caso y es importante que pienses en ello. Para el primer caso `AsyncTask` te viene muy bien. Ejecutas tu proceso pesado en el `doInBackground`, le informas al usuario sobre el progreso del mismo en el `publishProgress` y al final muestras el resultado en su pantalla a traves del `onPostExecute`. Es lo usual, no solo para realizar peticiones a servidores, tambien vale para cálculos complicados, búsquedas en base de datos, etc. Siempre y cuando tu intensión sea mantener al usuario a la espera de ese proceso (algo que puede ser molesto) y que pueda interactuar con la app una vez ha finalizado.

Para el segundo caso un `Thread` o un `Runnable` junto con un `Handler` te viene muy bien, ejecutas un proceso en un método `run` que es independiente de su estado de finalización y el usuario ni por enterado se da de esto.

Para el tercer caso, pongamos de ejemplo: Tienes un proceso que captura datos y los transforma en información útil, esta información la guardas en tu base de datos local pero también debes enviarla al servidor por cuestiones de redundancia de datos; pero también debes esperar el resultado del envío al servidor para actualizar un indicador sobre el registro que te defina si el envío fué exitoso o no, para no volver a enviarlo por ejemplo. Para este tipo de situaciones conviene trabajar con planificadores de Hilos que te permitan ejecutar una acción para el momento en el que el hilo termina su ejecución. Un ejemplo muy sencillo es [Google Guava](http://nohack.eingenetzt.com/java/java-guava-librarys-listeningexecutorservice-tutorial/) y sus clases `Futures` y `ListenableFuture`.

Es un poco de información adicional a lo que te han respondido que es bueno conocerla, así que define bien tus escenarios para que puedas elegir una mejor manera de trabajar.

Comment: Muy bien detallado para escoger el método más adecuado