# Error al mostrar imagen desde internet en android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando mostrar una imagen desde internet con el siguiente codigo:

```
try {
    final ImageView prueba2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pruebaImagen);

    URL url = new URL("http://www.expertoanimal.com/es/images/9/7/5/img_nombres_para_perros_originales_y_bonitos_5579_paso_1_600.jpg");

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    prueba2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

> Process: com.dedicables.videos.dedicable, PID: 24788
>                                                                                    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                                                                                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.Views.Login.Login.onCreateView(Login.java:92)

Donde me marca el error en la siguiente linea:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

He intentado con varias url y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Cerré la pregunta porque la descarga es correcta, el problema es realizar la operación en el Thread Principal. @EduardoJesus

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo la conexión en el hilo principal. Tienes que pasar esa petición a un hilo secundario. Para ello puedes utilizar un `AsyncTask` (en este caso esta clase estará contenida dentro de la clase que lleva tu código)

```
class GetImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
       prueba2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Luego deberás modificar tu código, para que tu `ImageView` prueba2 sea una variable de la clase para poder acceder a ella desde el `AsyncTask` y deberás crear esta así:

- Si la versión de `Android` es menor de la API 11: `new GetImageAsync().execute("http://www.expertoanimal.com/es/images/9/7/5/img_nombres_para_perros_originales_y_bonitos_5579_paso_1_600.jpg");`
- Si la versión de `Android` es mayor o igual a la API 11: `new GetImageAsync().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "http://www.expertoanimal.com/es/images/9/7/5/img_nombres_para_perros_originales_y_bonitos_5579_paso_1_600.jpg");`

En este enlace tienes bastante más información sobre los `AsyncTask`: http://jarroba.com/asynctask-en-android/

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El error

> **NetworkOnMainThreadException**: se provoca cuando tratas de realizar
>   operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.

Es relacionado a que se esta realizando una tarea en el hilo principal, lo cual es incorrecto puedes utilizar un [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) o simplemente [**runOnUiThread()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) que en este caso sería lo ideal ya que realizas solo un proceso de descarga.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {           


try {
                            final ImageView prueba2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pruebaImagen);

                            URL url = new URL("http://www.expertoanimal.com/es/images/9/7/5/img_nombres_para_perros_originales_y_bonitos_5579_paso_1_600.jpg");

                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            prueba2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

        }
    });
```

Se puede también usar un [**AsyncTask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), revisa esta pregunta:

[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549)