# Android: ¿Cómo refrescar un TextView cuando le asigno texto dentro de un AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

Tengo un `AsyncTask` en el cual obtengo unos datos, de los cuales uno de ellos debo asignárselo a un `TextView`, pero al asignarle el dato dentro del `AsyncTask` al `TextView` no toma el cambio, al salirme del `Fragment` (en el cual esta el `TextView` y el `AsyncTask`) y volver si se ve reflejado el cambio.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo debo hacer para refrescar el `TextView` sin necesidad de recargar otra vez todo el `fragment`?.

Comment: ¿En que función del AsynTask estas seteando el textview?.Puedes poner el código del AsynTask

Comment: @devjav veo necesario agregues el código para ver especificamente como tratas de cambiar el contenido del TextView, saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Dentro de [`onPostExecute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) puedes realizarlo ya que en este punto see pueden realizar operaciones en la UI, y no es necesario recargar el Fragment ni usar `runOnUiThread()` dentro de el:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
 { 
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextView);   
    textView.setText(valoraAcutalizar);

  }
```

---

Si la actualización se esta realizando en otro punto podrías considerar usar

Usa [**runOnUiThread()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {  
              TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextView);   
              textView.setText(valoraAcutalizar);                

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13549/95

Answer (score 1):

Lo más seguro es que necesites utilizar la función `runOnUiThread()` ya que como pone en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) sirve para ejecutar acciones en el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario. Esta función la deberás ejecutar dentro del `onPostExecute()` de tu `AsyncTask` quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
          public void run() {
                textView.setText(valoraAcutalizar);
          }
    });
}
```

---

Editado:

Para el caso que me comentas @devjav en el que el `AsynkTask` esta en otro clase a la del `Fragment`, te pongo como lo suelo hacer.

Lo que yo suelo hacer es crear `callbacks` hacia los `fragments`, en el caso de ejemplo que te pondré a continuación el `AsyncTask` está dentro del `Activity` que contiene a los tabs y el contenedor de fragments.

Aquí tienes un poco de documentación:

- [Crear callbacks de eventos a la actividad.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)
- [Communicating with other fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
- [How to define Callbacks in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3398416/3683321)
- [Callbacks en Android](http://www.thelastbug.es/android/callbacks-en-android/) (Este último creo que se aproxima más a lo que quieres)

Ejemplo:

**Código del Activity**

```
public class MiCentroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private OnActivityInteractionAgendaListener mListenerAgenda;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            .....

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
            adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            .....

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                  if(position == 0) {
                       AgendaFragment ag=  AgendaFragment.newInstance(position);
                       mListenerAgenda= (OnActivityInteractionAgendaListener) ag;
                       return ag;
                  }
            }
      }

      public interface OnActivityInteractionAgendaListener{
           void onParentInteraction(List<EventoAgendaDto> eventos, Long dia);
           void onParentInteractionClear();
      }

      private class ObtenerAgenda extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

             .....

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                   super.onPostExecute(result);

                    try {
                         if(mListenerAgenda!= null)
                              mListenerAgenda.onParentInteraction(eventos, dia);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
      }
}
```

**Código del Fragment**

```
public class AgendaFragment  extends Fragment implements  MiCentroActivity.OnActivityInteractionAgendaListener {
       private TextView fecha;
       private AgendaPublicaAdpater adapter;    

       @Override
       public void onParentInteraction(List<EventoAgendaDto> eventos, Long dia) {
             fecha.setText(Constants.sdfFecha.format(dia));
             adapter.updateList(eventos);
       }

       @Override
       public void onParentInteractionClear() {
             adapter.clear();
       }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Joacer, tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que yo tengo mi AsyncTask en una clase aparte, por lo cual, no podría tener acceso al TextView desde allí. ¿Que debería hacer?

Comment: @devjav he modificado mi respuesta para darte una aproximación a lo que me estás comentando, creo que con eso podrías conseguir tu objetivo