# Cómo puedo mostrar parte de JSON en un TextView en Android?

Tags: android, json, textview

Buenas a todos. Estoy atascado con esta pequeñez y no puedo lograr mostrar en un `TextView` sólo el horario de la estructura `JSON` que obtengo desde `URL`.
Mi idea era hacer lo siguiente con el TextView `tvHorarioTienda.setText(horario);`, el problema es que no puedo hacer uso de la variable horario en el `onCreate`. Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo? Desde ya, gracias.

Esta es la función que estoy utilizando para obtener JSON:

```
    public void obtenerHorarioTienda() {

    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

    String url2 = ("http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    String jsonStr2 = sh.makeServiceCall(url2);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr2);
        if (jsonStr2 != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(jsonStr2);
            JSONArray tiendasHorarios = jsonObj2.getJSONArray("tiendas");

            for (int i = 0; i < tiendasHorarios.length(); i++){
                JSONObject th = tiendasHorarios.getJSONObject(i);
                String horario = th.getString("horario");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JSON que recibo:

```
{ 'tiendas': [{ 'idt':'69', 'nombre': 'Arcoiris', 'horario': 'Lunes de 13 hs a 16 hs' }]}
```

Comment: Ben día; de Android (y de móviles desconozco) pero te sugiero mires usar el `onDraw`; el detalle con el `onCreate` es que se lanza cuando el componente no existe y por consiguiente "no hay nada del mismo que pueda ser usado", el `onDraw` es cuando ya existe su estructura; bueno usa otro evento que se lance "siempre" pero cuando ya existe el componente y está disponible para obtener y/o cambiar en el lo que requiere.

Answer (score 0):

El parser del dato es correcto, es un objeto que contiene un array llamado `tiendas`, el cual contiene uno o varios objetos del cual obtienes el valor de horario:

```
 {'tiendas': [{ 'idt':'69', 'nombre': 'Arcoiris', 'horario': 'Lunes de 13 hs a 16 hs' }]}
```

Para que puedas hacer uso de la variable en `onCreate()` , puedes definir una variable `horario` a nivel de clase, llamar el método y posteriormente de la obtención del valor agregar este a tu `TextView`:

```
private String horario = "";

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
      obtenerHorarioTienda();
    ...
      tvHorarioTienda.setText(horario);    
    ...
  }
```

---

Ya que estas realizando una conexión  en la llamada al método para realizar la consulta y obtener el valor de horario, en este caso estarías realizando una operación en el hilo principal y necesitarías una opción como el uso de `AsyncTask`, `Handler` o `runOnUiThread`, por ejemplo:

```
private String horario = "";

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {  

               obtenerHorarioTienda();   
               tvHorarioTienda.setText(horario);  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
  ...

  }
```

Te sugiero revises estas preguntas:

[Android: ¿Cómo refrescar un TextView cuando le asigno texto dentro de un AsyncTask?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36433/android-c%C3%B3mo-refrescar-un-textview-cuando-le-asigno-texto-dentro-de-un-asyncta/36439#36439)

[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13534#13534)

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, gracias por responder. No estaría funcionando, es como si no tomara la variable String horario quedara vacía, a pesar de que en el Android Monitor puedo ver que la respuesta es mi estructura JSON. Incluso intenté hacer un Intent hacia la misma clase, pero no funcionó.