# Error al insertar una imagen de una url en un imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, url, android-imageview

Buenas,

Me gustaría en mi aplicación poder cambiar la imagen de un ImageView sin tener que estar actualizando la app tan a menudo.
He pensado en guardar la imagen en un servidor web y poner que se descargue la imagen cada vez que se abra la app. Así cuando yo cambie la imagen en el servidor, esta se cambiará en la app.

El problema es que al intentar cambiar la imagen me da un error.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    public class FragmentInicio extends Fragment {

    private static URL imgurl;

    public FragmentInicio() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        ImageView logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageEccaInicio);
        try {
            imgurl = new URL("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/22/c8/9e/22c89e308d734b5daa9f383419b1bdc5.jpg");
            Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
            logo.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Se ha tocado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Llama al método openDrawer de la actividad principal para abrir el menú lateral.
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

Si comento todo lo que está dentro del try, la aplicación coge por defecto la imagen del layout y no da error. Pero me interesa que la imagen sea cogida desde la url que le paso.

Este es el error que da:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ecca.radio, PID: 2839
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ecca.radio/ecca.radio.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                      at ecca.radio.navigationDrawer.FragmentInicio.onCreateView(FragmentInicio.java:43)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, estoy aprendiendo mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error al parecer es por la conexión a internet intenta esto

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/22/c8/9e/22c89e308d734b5daa9f383419b1bdc5.jpg");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitMap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**

Tal como comenta @Error404, esta tarea debe llamarse desde una tarea asincrona, ya que la estas intentando ejecutar una operacion request desde internet en el hilo principal, sumándome a esta idea podrías intentar algo así

```
private class GetImageToURL extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Bitmap > {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitMap) {
        logo.setImageBitmap(myBitMap);
    }
}
```

Y la llamas

```
new GetImageToURL().execute("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/22/c8/9e/22c89e308d734b5daa9f383419b1bdc5.jpg");
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public class FragmentInicio extends Fragment {

    private static URL imgurl;
    public ImageView logo;
    public FragmentInicio() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageEccaInicio);
        new GetImageToURL().execute("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/22/c8/9e/22c89e308d734b5daa9f383419b1bdc5.jpg");
        return v;
    }

    private class GetImageToURL extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Bitmap > {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log exception
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap myBitMap) {
            logo.setImageBitmap(myBitMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, he entendido que en el activity principal no puedo hacer una conexión en red. Pero tengo una duda, en el método onPostExecute que se le pasa un BitMap, asigna a logo la imágen. No entiendo cómo declarar logo en esa clase si ya está en la otra clase. No se le puede pasar por parámetros cómo se hace con la url. Y si lo intento declarar tendría que tener un view en esta clase ¿no?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que dentro de tu Activity, debes declarar esta clase, no en un archivo aparte. Por otro lado, debes declarar como `public` la variable logo, ACTUALICE mi respuesta para que veas como deberia quedar @Natlum

Comment: Mil gracias no había caído en ese detalle, todo ha funcionado perfectamente.

Comment: un gusto, saludos! @Natlum

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como dice la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), si estas usando una versión igual o superior a `Honeycomb`, este error se produce porque estás intentando ejecutar la operación de red en el hilo principal.

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>   This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher.

Por lo tanto, lo que podrías realizar sería englobar tu código en el método `doInBackground` de una `AsyncTask`, el cual se ejecuta como una tarea asíncrona.

Answer (score 1):

El error [**NetworkOnMainThreadException**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html):

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

**indica que se esta realizando operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.**

Para evitar esto puedes hacer uso de [**runOnUiThread()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)), [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) o también [**Handler.post()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).

---

ejemplo `runOnUiThread()`:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {  
               proceso(); //Realizar aquí tu proceso!                    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

ejemplo para usar en tu código:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    ImageView logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageEccaInicio);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {  

                imgurl = new URL("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/22/c8/9e/22c89e308d734b5daa9f383419b1bdc5.jpg");
                Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
               logo.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);


               logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view){
               //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Se ha tocado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              //Llama al método openDrawer de la actividad principal para abrir el menú lateral.
              ((MainActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();
                }
              });


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
    }
});


    return v;
}
```

Se tiene una pregunta similar en SO:

**[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro)**