# Actualizar activity desde un hilo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Quería lanzar una pregunta en modo teoría y saber vuestra opinión, respecto a si es factible o no y en caso afirmativo si lo consideráis buena práctica o no.

> ¿Es factible actualizar una activity desde un thread?

Hablo de aplicaciones nativas de Android.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Es factible actualizar una activity desde un thread?

Es factible, aunque regularmente se realiza fuera de un `Thread` o cuando se finaliza la ejecución de un proceso en el mismo (por ejemplo `onPostExecute()` en un `Asynctask`), si deseas abrir una `Activity` desde un `Thread`, como una opción usa un [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) mediante [getMainLooper()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper())

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
      public void run() {
          Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, OtraActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
   });
```

No lo consideraría buena práctica, pero depende de los requerimientos de tu aplicación, en ocasiones es necesario realizar "unicornios".

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys. Más o menos esa fue mi respuesta en una entrevista de trabajo y la contestación por parte del especialista que me hizo la entrevista fue que no era posible.

Comment: Definitivamente es posible, de hecho puedes realizar cualquier operación en el Main Thread si deshabilitas la politica http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13522/95 pero no es recomendable http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13549/95 , prueba también con el script que agrego en mi respuesta.

Comment: @Rafa de donde eres Rafa y que empresa fue hahaha :D