# ¿Como conectarse mediante FTP en Android?

Tags: java, android, ftp

Estoy tratando de conectarme localmente al servidor FTP para recuperar unos archivos y leerlos.

El programa peta al hacer la conexión al servidor "localhost".

> 02-02 11:34:38.472 3867-3867/com.mimapa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                         Process: com.mimapa, PID: 3867
>                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mimapa/com.mimapa.CrearModificar}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                          Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>                                                             at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>                                                             at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>                                                             at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:708)
>                                                             at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
>                                                             at com.utils.FtpControl.conectar(FtpControl.java:101)
>                                                             at com.mimapa.CrearModificar.leerArchivos(CrearModificar.java:65)
>                                                             at com.mimapa.CrearModificar.onCreate(CrearModificar.java:39)
>                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Por otro lado he programado la misma clase pero en NetBeans y el funcionamiento es correcto, puedo conectarme y leer los archivos. 
Solo tengo el problema con Android Studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {     Button btMapas;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btMapas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMapa);
    btMapas.setEnabled(true);

    leerArchivos(); }


private void leerArchivos() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FtpControl ftpControl = new FtpControl("localhost", "userftp", "admin");
    ftpControl.conectar();
    String[] lista = ftpControl.listaArchivos("/srv/ftp/");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            br = ftpControl.descargarArchivo("/srv/ftp/" + lista[i]);
            if (br != null) {
                guardarUsuario(
                        br.readLine(),
                        br.readLine(),
                        br.readLine(),
                        br.readLine()
                );
            }
            br.close();
        }

        ftpControl.cerrar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void guardarUsuario(String nombre, String lat, String log, String fecha) {
    MyDataBase admin = new MyDataBase(this,
            null, null, 1);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // Pares clave-valor
    values.put(UsuarioContract.UsuarioEntry.ORGANIZACION, "Grupo A");
    values.put(UsuarioContract.UsuarioEntry.USUARIO_APP, 0);
    values.put(UsuarioContract.UsuarioEntry.USUARIO, nombre);
    values.put(UsuarioContract.UsuarioEntry.LONGITUD, log);
    values.put(UsuarioContract.UsuarioEntry.LATITUD, lat);
    values.put(UsuarioContract.UsuarioEntry.ACTIVADO, 0);
    Controlador.guardarUsuario(admin, values);
}
```

Clase conexion ftp:

```
public class FtpControl {

// datos
private  String servidor;
private  String usuario;
private  String pass;

private FTPClient cliente = null;

public FtpControl(String servidor, String usuario, String pass) {
    this.servidor = servidor;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.pass = pass;
}

public boolean subirArchivo(String path, String nombre) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    // si el usuario esta conectado al servidor
    if (cliente.isConnected()) {
        try {
            cliente.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            cliente.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            cliente.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            cliente.storeFile(nombre, fis);
            cerrar(); // cerrar sesion
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public String[] listaArchivos(String path) {
    String[] lista = null;

    try {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = cliente.listFiles(path);
        int length = ftpFiles.length;
        lista = new String[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

            if (isFile) {
                lista[i] = name;
            } else {
                lista[i] = name;
            }
        }
        return lista;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lista;
}

public BufferedReader descargarArchivo(String path) {
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(path);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return br;
}

public void conectar() {
    new Connection().execute();
}

public void cerrar() {
    try {
        cliente.logout();
        cliente.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private class Connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        cliente = new FTPClient();

        try {
            // conectar al servidor
            cliente.connect(servidor, 21);
            cliente.login(usuario, pass);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que obtienes es debido a que estas realizando operaciones en el hilo principal:

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Puedes usar como opción un `AsyncTask` para ejecutar el método `leerArchivos()`, no es necesario agregar todo el código dentro del AsyncTask solo la llamada al método:

```
 private class LeeArchivos extends AsyncTask<Void , Integer, Long>
    {
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            leerArchivos();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          //Termina proceso
            Log.i("TAG" , "Termina proceso de lectura de archivos.");
        }
    }
```

De esta forma llamarías el proceso:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btMapas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMapa);
    btMapas.setEnabled(true);

    //leerArchivos();
    new LeeArchivos().execute(); //*Llama AsyncTask.

}
```

Otra opción es usar `runOnUiThread`:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {  

               leerArchivos(); //Realizar aquí tu proceso!                    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Revisa una explicación más amplia de este error:

[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro)

Comment: Seria importante  agregar la razón del -1 .

Comment: Aun sigues tenido tu fan, que le da a todas tus publicaciones -1

Comment: @AshleyG. Si, no importa me asigne negativos, lo malo es que asigna positivos a respuestas que en ocasiones no lo son o son incorrectas, y esto es malo para el sitio. No me imagino que persona puede realizar esto cada día, ir sobre un usuario en particular y puntuarlo negativo por razón desconocida.

Comment: Que tal, probé esta solución el día de ayer y me funciono bárbaro!; sin embargo, me surgió otro detalle, pero fuera de la línea de esta pregunta. Muchas gracias por la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));
ftpClient.login(user, password);
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(serverRoad);
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.storeFile("test.txt", buffIn);
buffIn.close();
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Te dejo el enlace para más información : [Aqui](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)

Comment: Hola Solamente. Para que una respuesta sea de calidad , no dejes *solamente* el código y un enlace. Pon la explicacion en la respuesta. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: He probado ese código pero sigue sin funcionar, la clase la tengo hecha y me funciona en el NetBeans como digo, el problema viene al utilizarla en una aplicación de Android Studio, cuando útilizo el debug, el programa peta a la hora de hacer la conexión al servidor.

Comment: Puedes poner el log del error para tener mas información?

Comment: @solamente añadido, soy nuevo en el Android Studio y no encontraba el log

Comment: Creo que tengo una idea de porque te esta fallando el código puedes copiar tu main activity donde estas haciendo la llamada? Creo que es porque la estas haciendo directamente en lugar de usar un thread.

Comment: @solamente exacto, he encontrado mas o menos la solución gracias al error que me salia, he conseguido que se conecte con un AsyncTask y ahora trato de leer los archivos, el error ahora es que "La conexión no esta abierta". Es necesario que todo el código este dentro de un AsyncTask?

Comment: jeje eso es otra cosa por lo menos hemos descubierto este te sugiero que si es otro error habrás una nueva pregunta y esta vez añade el log de error suele ser una gran ayuda. Saludos!