# Leer JSON por OpenHttpConnection en una IP Publica

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, app

Tengo un problema al tratar de leer un JSON por OpenHttpConnection en una IP Publica.

Probé le link del JSON y está perfecto, pero cuando intento hacer la lectura del JSON tengo el siguiente mensaje por Log:

D/NetWorkSecurityConfig: No NetWork Security Config specified, using platform dafault

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class Koneksi {

public String call(String url) {
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    int charRead;
    String str = "";
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {
        while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
            String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
            str += readString;
            inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return str;
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String url) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;
    URL url1 = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = url1.openConnection();
    //if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
      //  throw new IOException("Not An Http Connection");
    //Log.d("ERROR: ", ": ERROR DE HTTP CONNECTION");
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpconn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpconn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpconn.connect();

        response = httpconn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpconn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR: ", e.getMessage() + ": ERROR DE CONEXION");
        throw new IOException("Error connecting2");
    }
    return in;
}
```

}

Otra Clase

```
public class Biodata extends Koneksi {

    String URL = "http://MIIPPUBLICA:8000/Android/server.php";
    String url = "";
    String response = "";

    public String vista() {
        try {
            url = URL + "?operasi=view";
            System.out.println("URL Tampil Biodata: " + url);
            response = call(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR APP: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE PREDETERMINADO DE ERROR");
        }
        return response;
    }

    public String insertar(String nama, String alamat) {
        try {
            url = URL + "?operasi=insert&nama=" + nama + "&alamat=" + alamat;
            System.out.println("URL Insert Biodata : " + url);
            response = call(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR APP: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE PREDETERMINADO DE ERROR");
        }
        return response;
    }

    public String getData(int id) {
        try {
            url = URL + "?operasi=get_biodata_by_id&id=" + id;
            System.out.println("URL Insert Biodata : " + url);
            response = call(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR APP: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE PREDETERMINADO DE ERROR");
        }
        return response;
    }

    public String actualizar(String id, String nama, String alamat) {
        try {
            url = URL + "?operasi=update&id=" + id + "&nama=" + nama + "&alamat=" + alamat;
            System.out.println("URL Insert Biodata : " + url);
            response = call(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;
    }

    public String borrar(int id) {
        try {
            url = URL + "?operasi=delete&id=" + id;
            System.out.println("URL Insert Biodata : " + url);
            response = call(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR APP: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE PREDETERMINADO DE ERROR");
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Mi AdroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tecnologia.crud_android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era un problema de permisos, finalmente pude resolverlo con esto dentro del onCreate

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: **Esto no tiene que ver con el mensaje, esto lo que evita es el error NetworkOnMainThreadException, en realidad esto que realizas no se debe realizar para aplicaciones en producción**, en realidad tienes que usar un AsyncTask o runOnUIThread :  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549

Answer (score -1):

**Actualización:**

Este mensaje puede se muestra también cuando se realiza una petición a internet pero no se tiene definido dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` el permiso:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

No es un error en realidad, es un mensaje de debug:

> D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default

si no logras leer el json debe ser otro el problema, revisa en el LogCat por mensajes definidos con el tag `E/` y el mensaje "Caused by:".

Te aconsejo definir los mensajes de error en el logCat como Errores, usando Log.e() en lugar de Log.d():

```
catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.d("ERROR APP: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE PREDETERMINADO DE ERROR");
            Log.e("ERROR APP: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE PREDETERMINADO DE ERROR");
        }
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.