# ¿Cómo cargar un método al iniciar aplicación en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una aplicación en la cual quiero que haga una validación y si es correcta me mande a otra UI, por parte del código funciona correctamente. Mi duda es en donde poner el método para que al iniciar la aplicación haga la validación y realice la acción programada.

**Nota:** Intente poner el método en el onCreate del Activity con el que inicia la app, pero sigo sin resultados.

Método onCreate:

```
@Override
```

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){`

```
cargarSesion();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContextView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

iniciar_sesion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inicio_sesion);
iniciar_sesion.setOnClickListener(this);

registrarse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registrarse);
registrarse.setOnClickListener(this);}
```

Métodos cargados

```
 public String validacionUser(){
                        //Carga de preferencias del usuario
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user = preferences.getString("usuario","No hay nada guardado");
    password = preferences.getString("contrasenia","No hay nada guardado");

    URL url = null;
    String line = "";
    String webServiceResult="";

    try {
        url= new URL("https://url_que_solicito/Login.php?contra="+password+"&email="+user);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();//Se abre la conexion
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {//mientras exista un resultado los ira almacenando en la variable
            webServiceResult += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return webServiceResult;//Resultado del servidor (convertido en JSON)
}

                            //Método para iniciar sesion en caso de que la validación sea correcta
public void cargarSesion(){
    try {
        String resultJSON="";
        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject  (validacionUser());//Se guarda el resultado obtenido del JSON
        resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");//guarda el registro del arreglo estado
        if (resultJSON.equals("1")) {      // el correo y contraseña son correctas
            cargarPrincipal();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (resultJSON.equals("2")){//el ususario no existe
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido a SavEnergy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: hablas del metodo `cargarSesion()`

Comment: Podrías poner todo tú código y el del método `cargarSesión();`?

Comment: Precisamente esta es la solución : "Intente poner el método en el onCreate del Activity con el que inicia la app, pero sigo sin resultados." , cual es la razón por la que no funciono? revisaste el Log? algún NetworkOnMainThreadException.? aporta mas información, agrega el método para saber que realiza, saludos!.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta y en efecto, quiero que cargue primero el método `cargarSeson();`

Comment: si miraste si el resultado del json es 1 o 2?

Comment: @MiguelAngel estas realizando una operación de conexión en el Thread principal. Agrego una repuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun veo tu método validacionUser() intenta acceder a (https://url_que_solicito/Login.php?...), debes saber que no puedes realizar ninguna tarea de red o por internet de manera directa, te sugiero usar una tarea asíncrona (AsyncTask), sería más o menos así:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContextView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            user = preferences.getString("usuario","No hay nada guardado");
            password = preferences.getString("contrasenia","No hay nada guardado");
            URL url = null;
            String line = "";
            String webServiceResult="";
            try {
                url= new URL("https://url_que_solicito/Login.php?contra="+password+"&email="+user);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();//Se abre la conexion
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {//mientras exista un resultado los ira almacenando en la variable
                    webServiceResult += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return webServiceResult;//Resultado del servidor (convertido en JSON)
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String webServiceResult) {
            super.onPostExecute(webServiceResult);
            try {
                String resultJSON="";
                JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(webServiceResult);//Se guarda el resultado obtenido del JSON
                resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");//guarda el registro del arreglo estado
                if (resultJSON.equals("1")) {      // el correo y contraseña son correctas
                    cargarPrincipal();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (resultJSON.equals("2")){//el ususario no existe
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido a SavEnergy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

Y nunca olvides imprimir los Exceptions...  espero te ayude

Answer (score -1):

Revisando lo que tratas de realizar, el problema es que estas realizando esta tarea en el hilo principal, esto porque se esta llamando a realizar una conexión desde `onCreate()`, esto genera un error [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549).

> **[NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549)**: se provoca cuando tratas de realizar
>   operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.

En realidad en `onCreate()` es donde debes llamar los métodos para tu propósito que es ¿Cómo cargar un método al iniciar aplicación en Android?.

Para evitar este problema, llama los métodos `validacionUser()` :

```
 AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

             validacionUser();        

            }
        });
```

y `cargarSesion()` en un `AsyncTask` dentro de `onCreate()` :

```
 AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

             cargarSesion();        

            }
        });
```

Recuerda que la ejecución del `AsyncTask` es asíncrona así que al entrar tu aplicación puede tardar un poco en realizar la tarea.

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.