# Descargar archivo desde url en adroid

Tags: android

Estoy intentando obtener un archivo a traves de una URL y quiero meterlo en una variable file, habia intentado algo asi:

```
URL url = new URL ("http://camporeal.tv/Examen.docx");
URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlCon.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Ejemplo11111111111122222222.docx");
byte [] array = new byte[1000];
int leido = is.read(array);
while (leido > 0) {
    fos.write(array,0,leido);
    leido=is.read(array);
}
is.close();
fos.close();
```

Pero nada.

Comment: Cual es el problema o el error que obtienes? Que despliega el LogCat? Pueden ser varias cosas, por eso es importante agregar mas detalles.

Comment: era un error de permisos, ya lo consegui

Comment: Son varias cosas que debes contemplar, revisa mi respuesta, saludos. @juanjo

Answer (score 0):

#### Guardar archivo desde una url en Android.

Para esto necesitas tener en cuenta varias cosas,

**1)** Asignar permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

para dispositivos con Android 6.0+ el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE debe ser requerido manualmente.

**2)** No definas la ruta destino ya que el path puede no encontrarse en ciertos dispositivos, lo correcto es usar el método [**Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Ejemplo.docx
```

de esta forma se obtendrá la ruta: `/storage/emulated/0/Ejemplo.docx`

**3)** Usa un Asynctask para evitar operaciones en el Thread principal para evitar [NetworkonMainThreadException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549).

Este sería un Asynctask al cual le envias la url del archivo a descargar y la ruta en la que deseas se escriba el archivo, contiene la petición de permisos:

```
   public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        private Context mContext;

        public DownloadFile (Context context){
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    checkExternalStoragePermission();
                }

                //Url de descarga
                String url  = strings[0];
                //Path destino
                String outputPath  = strings[1];
                Log.i(TAG, "* Url source: " + url);
                Log.i(TAG, "* output Path: " + outputPath);

                File outputFile = new File(outputPath);

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                URL u = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)  u.openConnection();
                int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

                DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

                byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
                stream.readFully(buffer);
                stream.close();

                DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "* FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                return false; // swallow a 404
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "* IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                return false; // swallow a 404
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Para llamar este `AsyncTask` simplemente define el contexto, la url del archivo a descargar y el path destino:

```
  new DownloadFile(this).execute("http://camporeal.tv/Examen.docx", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Ejemplo.docx");
```