# Aplicación crashea cuando envío datos a través de un Socket en android

Tags: java, android, socket

Pulso el botón para enviar un texto a través de un socket y provoca un error que cierra mi aplicación, no se si estará bien definido el socket.

```
botonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            elementoSalida.setText("asdf");

            try {

                Socket miSocket = new Socket("192.168.100.190",9999);

                DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(miSocket.getOutputStream());

                flujoSalida.writeUTF(elementoEntrada.getText().toString());

                flujoSalida.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                elementoSalida.setText(e1.getMessage());
            }
        }
});
```

En los logs cuando pulso el botón me registra este error

> 2018-11-02 10:53:37.583 10993-10993/com.example.nacho.clientesocket E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.nacho.clientesocket, PID: 10993
>       android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>           at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:355)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:565)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:445)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:217)
>           at com.example.nacho.clientesocket.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

En androidManifest tengo definido el permiso de internet

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Si quito el permiso me da error de que no puede establecer conexión pero no crashea.

Comment: El primer sitio a revisar es siempre la documentación: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El problema es que estas realizando una operación en el hilo principal (main thread)**, como opción para evitar le excepción [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) es usar un [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

```
   botonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               String mensaje = "asdf";

                new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                        String mensaje = strings[0];
                        try {
                            Socket miSocket = new Socket("192.168.100.190", 9999);
                            DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(miSocket.getOutputStream());
                            flujoSalida.writeUTF(elementoEntrada.getText().toString());
                            flujoSalida.close();

                        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                            mensaje = e1.getMessage();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            mensaje = e1.getMessage();//  elementoSalida.setText(e1.getMessage());
                        }

                        return mensaje;
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        elementoSalida.setText(result);
                    }
                }.execute(mensaje);
            }
    });
```

Revisa esta pregunta, donde se provoca el mismo error porque se trata de realizar una conexión en el hilo principal pero usando `HttpUrlConnection` :

[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro/13549#13549)

---

Recuerda que es importante definir el permiso ya que tu aplicación realizará una conexión a internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```