# No logro abrir un pdf desde almacenamiento interno en android

Tags: android, pdf

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion que almacene un pdf en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo para posteriormente abrirlo, encontre un codigo para descargar archivos desde una url y otro para abrir el pdf, ambos funcionan por separado, se crea correctamente el archivo en el almacenamiento y se puede abrir con el device manager, y el otro metodo es capaz de abrir pdf de urls en internet, pero cuando intento abrir un pdf almacenado localmente no funciona

mi clase

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

File elarchivo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File dir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/lecciones");

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    elarchivo = new File(dir, "test.pdf");
    descargarLeccion();
    Button boton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirArchivo(getApplicationContext(), "test");
        }
    });


}

public void descargarLeccion() {

    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT > 8) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            //primero especificaremos el origen de nuestro archivo a descargar utilizando
            //la ruta completa
            URL url = new URL("https://si.ua.es/es/documentos/documentacion/pdf-s/mozilla12-pdf.pdf");

            //establecemos la conexión con el destino
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //establecemos el método jet para nuestra conexión
            //el método setdooutput es necesario para este tipo de conexiones
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //por último establecemos nuestra conexión y cruzamos los dedos
            urlConnection.connect();

            //vamos a establecer la ruta de destino para nuestra descarga
            //para hacerlo sencillo en este ejemplo he decidido descargar en
            //la raíz de la tarjeta SD

            //vamos a crear un objeto del tipo de fichero
            //donde descargaremos nuestro fichero, debemos darle el nombre que
            //queramos, si quisieramos hacer esto mas completo
            //cogeríamos el nombre del origen

            //utilizaremos un objeto del tipo fileoutputstream
            //para escribir el archivo que descargamos en el nuevo

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(elarchivo);

            //leemos los datos desde la url
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //creamos un buffer y una variable para ir almacenando el
            //tamaño temporal de este
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            //ahora iremos recorriendo el buffer para escribir el archivo de destino
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

            }
            //cerramos
            fileOutput.close();

            //y gestionamos errores
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void abrirArchivo(Context context, String archivo) {
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(elarchivo);
        // Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://si.ua.es/es/documentos/documentacion/pdf-s/mozilla12-pdf.pdf");
        Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        //obtenemos la extension del archivo y su mime type para abrirlo
        String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
        String mimetype = "";

        if (extension != null && extension.length() > 0)
            mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase());
        else {
            //mimetype = "*/*";
            mimetype = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(archivo + "pdf");

        }

        //    Log.i(tag, "uri: " + uri.toString() + "extension: "+ extension + " mimetype: " + mimetype);

        intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, /*mimetype*/ "application/pdf");
        //             intentUrl.setData(uri);
        intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intentUrl);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No app instalada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "error abriendo el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

El intent se ejecuta perfectamente por lo que no se genera ninguna excepcion de las que se atrapan ahi, si no que el app que abre el pdf se cierra y me tira algun error como, "No se pudo abrir el archivo " o "El archivo esta dañado o inexistente", note que si las rutas estaban incorrectas pasaba lo mismo asi que cree la variable global elarchivo para que ambos tuvieran exactamante la misma ruta, pero sin ningun resultado,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno he logrado solucionarlo con este codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    File elarchivo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (checkStoragePermission()){
            descargarLeccion("test");
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);
            descargarLeccion("test");
        }

        Button boton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                abrirArchivo(getApplicationContext(), "test");
            }
        });


    }

    public void descargarLeccion(String nombre) {

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDFS/");

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        elarchivo = new File(dir, nombre);

        int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (SDK_INT > 8) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            try {
                //primero especificaremos el origen de nuestro archivo a descargar utilizando
                //la ruta completa
                URL url = new URL("https://si.ua.es/es/documentos/documentacion/pdf-s/mozilla12-pdf.pdf");

                //establecemos la conexión con el destino
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //establecemos el método jet para nuestra conexión
                //el método setdooutput es necesario para este tipo de conexiones
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //por último establecemos nuestra conexión y cruzamos los dedos
                urlConnection.connect();

                //vamos a establecer la ruta de destino para nuestra descarga
                //para hacerlo sencillo en este ejemplo he decidido descargar en
                //la raíz de la tarjeta SD

                //vamos a crear un objeto del tipo de fichero
                //donde descargaremos nuestro fichero, debemos darle el nombre que
                //queramos, si quisieramos hacer esto mas completo
                //cogeríamos el nombre del origen

                //utilizaremos un objeto del tipo fileoutputstream
                //para escribir el archivo que descargamos en el nuevo

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(elarchivo);

                //leemos los datos desde la url
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                //creamos un buffer y una variable para ir almacenando el
                //tamaño temporal de este
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                //ahora iremos recorriendo el buffer para escribir el archivo de destino
                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                }
                //cerramos
                fileOutput.close();

                //y gestionamos errores
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void abrirArchivo(Context context, String archivo) {
        try {
            String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDFS/" + archivo + ".pdf";
            Toast.makeText(context, "ruta:  " + dir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File f = new File(dir);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //obtenemos la extension del archivo y su mime type para abrirlo
            String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
            String mimetype = "";

            if (extension != null && extension.length() > 0)
                mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase());
            else {
                //mimetype = "*/*";
                mimetype = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(archivo + "pdf");

            }

            //    Log.i(tag, "uri: " + uri.toString() + "extension: "+ extension + " mimetype: " + mimetype);

            intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, mimetype );
            //             intentUrl.setData(uri);
            intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intentUrl);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No app instalada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "error abriendo el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public boolean checkStoragePermission(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Con este codigo he logrado que se guardara y se abriera correctamente, el pdf queda guardado en la raiz del almacenamiento principal seleccionado del dispositivo, y cambiando extensiones valdria para descargar y abrir cualquier tipo de archivo.

Comment: No debe usarse : StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();

Comment: Si lo se solo tome la salida mas rapida al error xD, cual es el modo correcto, de paso lo corrijo

Comment: ok XD puedes usar un Asynctask para eso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/210135/aplicaci%c3%b3n-crashea-cuando-env%c3%ado-datos-a-trav%c3%a9s-de-un-socket-en-android/210201#210201 saludos.

Comment: ah solo es por lo de no hacer cosas de internet en el hilo principal... pense que era un protocolo http o algo asi, gracias lo checare

Answer (score 2):

A parecer estas creando el directorio pero no el archivo, usa e método `createNewFile()` para esto:

```
...
...
elarchivo = new File(dir, "test.pdf");
//Crea archivo
        try {
          elarchivo.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
...
```

revisa este ejemplo:

[Visualizar y crear archivos pdf android studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317187/visualizar-y-crear-archivos-pdf-android-studio/317355#317355)

Comment: Pues al explorar los archivos si encuentro mi pdf ahi, y ya he usado este mismo codigo para almacenar imágenes y funciona. Pero lo checare a ver como me va

Comment: No funciono, como digo el archivo si se crea correctamente y se puede abrir desde explorador de archivos, pero al hacerlo con el otro metodo que tambien funciona con pdf de internet, no carga, pero el intent no lanza excepciones

Comment: @CristianGil adjunta el log en la pregunta

Comment: ya lo solucione solo es cosa de rutas, y el error lo tiraba ya la aplicacion destinada a abrir el pdf y no la mia, por lo que ahi no tendria logs