# Interceptar WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop Android Studio

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una App en Android para un Escáner de la compañía Honeywell que al leer códigos de (Barras, QR o DataMatrix) busca información a un servidor de **SQL Server** mediante **jtds-1.3.1**, el dispositivo se conecta a la red local mediante **WIFI** y la aplicación funciona correctamente, el problema esta en que cuando los usuarios se mueven por las instalaciones se pierde la señal y les manda el mensaje de "Aplicación no responde" (ANR)

[image: Aplicación no responde]

y la App ya no se puede recuperar, para simular el error hago la conexión a una IP incorrecta cuando lo corro en Android Studio me arroja lo siguiente:

> I/zygote64: Thread[3,tid=23306,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x6fd3824200,peer=0x1bb40020,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

en este caso yo se que el error es porque pierde la conexión y que este es un proceso que esta tardando demasiado [Documentacion error ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr)
, este es el código para hacer la conexión a la base de datos:

```
    public Connection ConectarBD(){
    Connection La_Conexion=null;
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        //(CONEXION IP INCORRECTA para simular el error)
        La_Conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.10.10.00;databaseName=BASEDATOS;user=USUARIO;password=12345;");        
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return La_Conexion;
}
```

El mensaje del **Toast** nunca lo muestra, mi pregunta es:

como puedo detectar esta falla en la conexión y evitar que la App se cierre?

Una vez detectando el error, yo ya puedo fácilmente hacer que reintente mas tarde, pero de momento esto es lo que me detiene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente tenìas un error del tipo `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

> `NetworkOnMainThreadException`: se provoca cuando tratas de realizar
> operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo cual es incorrecto.

por esta razòn agregaste:

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Lo cual no deberìas usar en una aplicaciòn de producciòn, debes usar un `Asynctask`:
[Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException en usar HttpURLConnection de Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro)

o [Corrutinas si usas Kotlin en Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines)

**incluso usar `Asynctask` o `Corrutinas` evitara que tengas problemas de tipo `ANR` (Android Not Responding).**

---

Con respecto a el porque no se muestra el `Toast`, puede ser simplemente que al realizar la conexiòn no marca error o simplemente es nula, por lo que podrìas realizar otra validaciòn para mostrar otro `Toast`:

```
public Connection ConectarBD(){
    Connection La_Conexion=null;
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        //(CONEXION IP INCORRECTA para simular el error)
        La_Conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.10.10.00;databaseName=BASEDATOS;user=USUARIO;password=12345;");     

     if(La_Conexion == null){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se realizo conexiòn",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return La_Conexion;
}
```