# Enviar parámetro de un activity por método post a mi bd - kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buen dia.

Como puedo enviar datos que se ingresa en los TextView de mi activity registrar por el metodo Post a mi base de datos con php.

Este es mi archivo que espera los parametros a enviar.

grabar.php

```js
<?php 
ini_set('max_input_vars', 2000);
$servidor="miservidor";
$user="3979493_bd";
$clave="movilbd2021";
$bd="3979493_bd";

$con=new mysqli($servidor, $user, $clave, $bd);

$json=file_get_contents('php://input');

$data=json_decode($json);

$sql="    INSERT INTO persona (per_dni, per_apellidos, per_nombres, per_correo) 
    VALUES  ( '".$data->{'dni'}."','".$data->{'ape'}."',
          '".$data->{'nom'}."','".$data->{'cor'}."')";

$res=$con->query($sql);
if(!$res) $mensaje="ERROR";
else $mensaje="GRABADO";

@mysqli_free_result($res);
@mysqli_close($con);

header('Content-type: application/json');
/*echo '{"resultado":"'.$mensaje.'"}';*/
$response = array("resultado" => $mensaje);
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

y este es mi clase en kotlin donde lo mando los datos de manera directa.

```js
 fun registrarusuarios(url: String,nom:String,nick:String,clave:String){
        val JSON: MediaType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
        val postBody = "{  \"nombre\": \"" + nom + "\", \"nickuser\":\"" + nick + "\", \"clave\":\"" + clave + "\"} ".trimMargin()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(postBody.toRequestBody(JSON))
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
            if (!response.isSuccessful){
                Log.i("Error: ", "--------")
            }
            else {
                val jsonobject = JSONObject(response.body?.string())
                Log.i("mensaje: ", jsonobject.getString("resultado"))
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero lo que deseo es capturar los datos de los TextView que se va ingresando
alguna idea.

gracias por su tiempo.

Eh agregado en el mi registre.kt el siguiente codigo

```js
class Registrate : AppCompatActivity(),View.OnClickListener {
    var sp = slogin()
    private val btnLogin by bind<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
    private val btnregistrarte by bind<Button>(R.id.btnguardar)
    val edtNombre  by bind<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtnomuser)
    val nick_user by bind<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtemailuser)
    val  clave_user by bind<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtclavereg)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrate)
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this)
        btnregistrarte.setOnClickListener(this)


    }
    override fun onClick(p0: View?){

        when(p0?.id){

            R.id.btnLogin->{

                onBackPressed()
            }
            R.id.btnguardar->{
                val valorNombre = edtNombre.text.toString()
                val usernick = nick_user.text.toString()
                val claveuser =clave_user.text.toString()
                sp.registrarusuarios(Conexiones.urlreguser,valorNombre,usernick,claveuser)
                Toast.makeText(this@Registrate, "Registro Exitoso!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }


        }

    }
```

En donde le digo con el evento Clic si presiono el boton gauardar llama al metodo de la clase slogin = registrarusuario pero me arroja un error en la siguiente linea:

```
**sp.registrarusuarios(Conexiones.urlreguser,valorNombre,usernick,claveuser)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando `TextView` o `EditText`, primero obtén la referencia de la vista.

Por ejemplo suponiendo que tienes unos `EditText` con id `edtiTextNombre` y  `edtiTextApellido`en tu layout:

```
var edtNombre: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre)
var edtApellido: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edtiTextApellido)
```

y después obtén su texto el cual será usado para enviar como parámetro en la petición:

```
var valorNombre = edtNombre.text.toString()
var valorApellido = edtApellido.text.toString()
```

al obtener los valores, puedes usarlos en tu petición concatenando las variables, por ejemplo:

```
val postBody = "{  \"nombre\": \"" + valorNombre + "\", \"apellido\":\""+ valorApellido +"""\"}".trimMargin()
```

Comment: Estimado gracias por tu tiempo,pero eh editado la pregunta me esta saliendo un error en una linea de codigo el cual lo detallo en mi pregunta principal.

Comment: **Que error, es importante lo comentes en tu pregunta.**

Comment: en esta parte del activity    **sp.registrarusuarios(Conexiones.urlreguser,valorNombre,usernick,claveuser)**

Comment: Es importante el uso del LogCat ahí se muestra que tipo de error es.

Comment: ya solucione el problema solo tuve que agregar esta linea de codigo en mi activity en el onCreate agregue este     val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

Comment: ***Esto que mencionas no era parte de la pregunta original, es otro error muy diferente que seguramente es un NetworkonmainthreadException por eso es importante comentar cuál es el error y la solución que das no deberías usarla** a menos que sea un aplicación de prueba , usa un AsyncTask , revisa mi respuesta aquí : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13549/95