# Conexión Android Studio a MySQL me da error

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Estoy iniciándome en la programación y quiero hacer una conexión en Android Studio a una base de datos de MySQL. Entre lo que he mirado y lo que he ido aprendiendo he creado un método boolean en una clase para establecer una conexión

```
package com.example.conexion_mysql;
import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {

    public static boolean estableceConexion (){
        boolean conect;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base", "root", "1234");
            return conect=true;

        }catch (Exception e){
            return conect=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el Main Activity he creado un onClick con un botón que me devuelve un toast para comprobar si el método está estableciendo la conexión o no, y me da error de conexión.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button boton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.conecta);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (Conexion.estableceConexion()==true){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conexión establecida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Es por preguntaros cual es el motivo por el que puede fallar. Tengo en la carpeta libs el mysql-connector-java-5.1.49, lo he añadido como librería para que me de la implementación en el gradle y he dado permisos a internet en el manifest. He probado con el jdbc 49, con el 31, y con el más actual y nada...
Os agradecería muchísimo si me podéis ayudar para saber porque estoy fallando.

Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: No estoy seguro que puedas conectar de esta manera. El modo habitual de conectar con una  base de datos remota es usando Retrofit o Volley, pero para ello debes programar una API o Servicio REST en el servidor donde está la base de datos para que atienda a las solicitudes, que se enviarán vía HTTP. Si la BD está en el dispositivo Android, entonces lo mejor sería usar Room. Sea como sea, debes mostrar cuál es el error que estás teniendo.

Comment: Oe no mano, tu te pasas ya, como instalas mysql en tu celular?

Comment: Da risa tu comentario @Jimmy XD, pero a veces cuando se esta aprendiendo no se logra tener mucha logica para resolver problemas y muchas veces hasta el mas abusado tiene dificultades, ayudemos a entender la situacion en la que se encuentra para que pueda llegar a una solucion viable, concuerdo con el comentario el primer comentario aqui te dejo un link usando la libreria volley, a mi ver es la mas sencilla de utilizar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EgCtiytfR0

Comment: Gracias Cedano y Manny. Solo una pregunta, esto que me pasáis no es para bases de datos remotas? Quiero decir, yo estoy intentando hacer una conexión a una base de datos local, y me he basado, o al menos eso he intentado, en esto https://academiaandroid.com/ejemplo-conexion-android-con-base-datos-mysql/ y en esto https://www.programacion.com.py/moviles/android/utilizar-mysql-en-android-con-jdbc#google_vignette porque por ejemplo algo muy parecido si ha servido en eclipse, pero en android studio no lo conseguía y por eso la duda. Muchas gracias por todo!

Answer (score -1):

A simple vista tienes dos problemas importantes,

el primero es que **tu aplicación producirá un error del tipo `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, ya que no debes realizar tareas en el thread principal**, para esto puedes usar [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) (https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13549/95) o una `coroutina`:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        //proceso para revisar conexión
    }
```

El segundo detalle importante es que estás usando una url "localhost", esto puede funcionar en tu computadora, pero dentro de un dispositivo android no podrás acceder al recurso indicado por la url.

**si estás utilizando el emulador de Android y tienes mysql en tu misma PC, no debes utilizar `127.0.0.1` o `localhost` como IP, debes utilizar `10.0.2.2`**

Revisa:
[Android - Espacio de direcciones de Red](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)

---

Para concluir, en un ambiente de producción, lo ideal es que tu aplicación android consulte una API la cual realice las consultas a tu base de datos MySql.